# Changing font color and height of child in parent by calling the class in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a newbie. I have this code but the problem is i dont know how can i change the paragraph color of each child in the container. and also when i change the height of the 2nd child. Both 1st and 2nd child change height but i only want the child 2 to change height only. Please Help Thank You.

```css
.div-container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container{
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
.container:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.container:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #cdf1c3;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<title id="page-title"></title> 

<div class="div-container">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. At quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat.</p>


  </div>
  <div class="div-container">
    <h2 class="h2">Sample</h2>
    <p class="p2">P2</p>
    <p class="p3">p3</p>
    <p id="p4"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your paragraphs has a class or id, so you can use that to target the each paragraph separately.

For example:

```
.div-container .p2 {
    color: tomato;
}
```

Also, default align-items property for flex container is stretch, thats why both of your elements share the same height. You can disable that by setting it to flex-start for example.

```
.div-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D  really thank you for your help :D :)